# Split an element in an array into two in mongodb

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have an array of time periods on a mongo document.

it looks something like this

```
{
   spans: [{from:2016-1-1, to:2016-1-4}, 
           {from:2016-2-1, from:2016-2-4}]
}
```

I want to spit the first item into two (eg modify the existing element and add a new one) so that it looks like this

```
{
   spans: [{from:2016-1-1, to:2016-1-2}, 
           {from:2016-1-3, to:2016-1-4}, 
           {from:2016-2-1, from:2016-2-4}]
}
```

How can I do this in a single operation (I want it to succeed or fail together)?

I have tried doing an `addToSet` and `set` on the element but I cant as I get   :

> Cannot update 'spans' and 'spans.1.from' at the same time

I could do this by replacing the whole array at once but that seems extremely inefficient. I was wondering if there is a better way.

Comment: If you're looking for an atomic operation to do both I think that's not possible because the reason `Mongodb` focuses on atomic operations to do `one` thing only at a time. In any case, looking.

Comment: @SwagataPrateek Yeah I do really want it to be an atomic operation (at least from my applications perspective). Mongo does seem to allow a bundle of updates but only one at a time to a specific tree in the document.

Comment: Yeah. Same goes for multiple replacements. I would love this to be an atomic operation too. But I don't think it's there yet or I haven't seen yet in the docs pal.